# Error: the file can't be loaded by debugger plupin IDA PRO 64 bit

Tags: ida, debuggers, x86-64

I use IDA PRO 64bits on windows 10 64 bit, I want use it remote debug a file 64bit by linux. When I run linux_serverx64 in linux and connect then i error:  the file can't be loaded by debugger plupin IDA PRO 64 bit, Please verify that the parameters are valid, and in linux error: execvp(flag): 2: No such file or directory but file flag exist
. I try debug with file 32 bit, it is ok. Who can guide me how to fix it.